# Expect getting stuck when inside a foreach after first iteration

Tags: foreach, expect, spawn

Output is stuck after the first iteration. Works fine when only one expect exists within the loop. Using exp_continue as well fails when used.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

exp_internal 1
set timeout -1
set passwords [list foo bar test]
set connected false
set passwordUsed "test"
spawn ssh -oHostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-dss root@192.168.1.136 -y

foreach i $passwords {
    expect "assword:" { send -- "$i\r";}
    expect "asd" {send "test"}
}  
expect eof
```

Output:

```
spawn ssh -oHostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-dss root@192.168.1.136 -y



root@192.168.1.136's password: 



root@192.168.1.136's password:
```

debug

```
parent: waiting for sync byte
parent: telling child to go ahead
parent: now unsynchronized from child
spawn: returns {1937}

expect: does "" (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern "assword:"? no

expect: does "\r" (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern "assword:"? no

expect: does "\rroot@192.168.1.136's password: " (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern "assword:"? yes
expect: set expect_out(0,string) "assword:"
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp4"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) "\rroot@192.168.1.136's password:"
send: sending "foo\r" to { exp4 }

expect: does " " (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern "asd"? no

expect: does " \r\n" (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern "asd"? no

expect: does " \r\n\rroot@192.168.1.136's password: " (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern "asd"? no
```

Then hangs on the last expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The timeout value is the problem: expect is waiting forever to see "asd"

You need something like this (untested)

```
set passwords {foo bar baz}
set idx 0
spawn ...
expect {
    "assword:" {
        if {$idx == [llength $passwords]} {
            error "none of the passwords succeeded"
        }
        send "[lindex $passwords $idx]\r"
        incr idx
        exp_continue
    }
    "asd" {send "test"}
}
expect eof
```

`exp_continue` loops within the `expect` command to wait for "asd" or for "assword" to appear again.

The "asd" case does not use exp_continue, so after sending "test", *this* expect commend ends.

Comment: Would this expect be inside the for each loop? setting timeout to 10 actually "fixed" the getting stuck issue. Thanks!

Comment: Nope, the loop is not needed here. I'm handling that with `lindex` and the index arithmetic

Comment: Unless I'm not understanding your request: are you looping to find the _first_ successful password, or do you want to try _all_ the passwords?

Comment: would go through the whole list. Got it working by sending exit when ssh is succesful